# Get a count of total documents with MongoDB when using limit

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, casbah

I am interested in optimizing a "pagination" solution I'm working on with MongoDB. My problem is straight forward. I usually limit the number of documents returned using the `limit()` functionality. This forces me to issue a redundant query without the `limit()` function in order for me to also capture the total number of documents in the query so I can pass to that to the client letting them know they'll have to issue an additional request(s) to retrieve the rest of the documents.

Is there a way to condense this into 1 query? Get the total number of documents but at the same time only retrieve a subset using `limit()`? Is there a different way to think about this problem than I am approaching it?

Comment: I have had this scenario and have written the approach as an article for others to use in here https://beingnin.medium.com/implement-server-side-pagination-in-mongodb-with-total-count-cfbb11b5c956

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**No**, there is no other way. Two queries - one for count - one with limit. Or you have to use a different database. Apache Solr for instance works like you want. Every query there is limited **and** returns totalCount.

Comment: I'm not sure if "No" is quite the answer anymore now that we have mongoDb 3.4. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39784851/3654061

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this as I've been search for a solution myself. You can create an aggregation operation to return the total count as well as full documents according to a condition. 

You can also do one findAll based on conditions. Store the length of that array. And then slice out values according to your limit / offset values. 

Both of these options are only one call to the DB. The expense of the aggregation depends on how complex it is, same with the slice that you run on the returned array. Thoughts on this?

Comment: How about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56693959 for me seems to work. Compared to aggregation with a limit of 100 docs, runs even slightly (~2-3ms) faster on avg for me...

Comment: It could be done with one just query by using facet sub pipelines, however, the downside of this solution is that the $facet stage is way slower as it can't use indexes even if a match is used within, the difference can be noted with 10M documents. So, it would be better to have separate queries than just one.

Answer (score 99):

Mongodb **3.4** has introduced [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) aggregation

> which processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage
>   on the same set of input documents.

Using [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) and [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) you can find documents with [**`$limit`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and can get total count.

You can use below aggregation in mongodb **3.4**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "totalData": [
      { "$match": { }},
      { "$skip": 10 },
      { "$limit": 10 }
    ],
    "totalCount": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }}
    ]
  }}
])
```

Even you can use  [**`$count`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) aggregation which has been introduced in mongodb **3.6**.

You can use below aggregation in mongodb **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "totalData": [
      { "$match": { }},
      { "$skip": 10 },
      { "$limit": 10 }
    ],
    "totalCount": [
      { "$count": "count" }
    ]
  }}
])
```

Comment: check out the implementation https://beingnin.medium.com/implement-server-side-pagination-in-mongodb-with-total-count-cfbb11b5c956

Comment: If you're looking to get a total count of the data after the $match has happened, placing the $match before the $facet achieves this.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49483919/3362244) explains the same thing but much clearer.

Comment: THis answer returns the total count properly but its failing to return the totalData

Comment: Regarding the performance: the $facet stage, and its sub-pipelines, cannot make use of indexes, even if its sub-pipelines use $match or if $facet is the first stage in the pipeline. The $facet stage will always perform a COLLSCAN during execution.

Answer (score 20):

MongoDB allows you to use `cursor.count()` even when you pass `limit()` or `skip()`.

Lets say you have a `db.collection` with 10 items.

You can do:

```
async function getQuery() {
  let query = await db.collection.find({}).skip(5).limit(5); // returns last 5 items in db
  let countTotal = await query.count() // returns 10-- will not take `skip` or `limit` into consideration
  let countWithConstraints = await query.count(true) // returns 5 -- will take into consideration `skip` and `limit`
  return { query, countTotal } 
}
```

Comment: how about aggregate ?

Comment: Best one for me, I hate aggregations ^^. I find this way more simple and readable.

Comment: `.skip(5).limit(5)` does NOT return the last 5 items in the DB. It returns the second group of 5 items. `count()` will always return 10 no matter how many items there are, provided there are at least 10.

Comment: Why is countTotal and CountWithConstraints awaiting a promise?

Comment: Mongo version 4.4 & mongo node client version 4 doesn't show total item count.

Comment: `count()` has been deprecated since `4.0`. Use [countDocuments()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mongodb-method-db.collection.countDocuments) instead, once with just the query and once with the query + the pagination options

Answer (score 17):

Here's how to do this with **MongoDB 3.4+** (with Mongoose) using `$facets`. This examples returns a `$count` based on the documents *after* they have been matched.

```js
const facetedPipeline = [{
    "$match": { "dateCreated": { $gte: new Date('2021-01-01') } },
    "$project": { 'exclude.some.field': 0 },
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "data": [
        { "$skip": 10 },
        { "$limit": 10 }
      ],
      "pagination": [
        { "$count": "total" }
      ]
    }
  }
];

const results = await Model.aggregate(facetedPipeline);
```

This pattern is useful for getting pagination information to return from a REST API.

Reference: [MongoDB $facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

Comment: Note that when you do the match first in the pipeline and the the facet you are being able to hit the indexes. You can't hit indexes from $facet

Answer (score 12):

Times have changed, and I believe you can achieve what the OP is asking by using aggregation with `$sort`, `$group` and `$project`. For my system, I needed to also grab some user info from my `users` collection. Hopefully this can answer any questions around that as well. Below is an aggregation pipe. The last three objects (sort, group and project) are what handle getting the total count, then providing pagination capabilities.

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  { $match: { public: true },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'userId',
    foreignField: 'userId',
    as: 'userInfo'
  } },
  { $project: {
    postId: 1,
    title: 1,
    description: 1
    updated: 1,
    userInfo: {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          firstUser: {
            $arrayElemAt: ['$userInfo', 0]
          }
        },
        in: {
          username: '$$firstUser.username'
        }
      }
    }
  } },
  { $sort: { updated: -1 } },
  { $group: {
    _id: null,
    postCount: { $sum: 1 },
    posts: {
      $push: '$$ROOT'
    }
  } },
  { $project: {
    _id: 0,
    postCount: 1,
    posts: {
      $slice: [
        '$posts',
        currentPage ? (currentPage - 1) * RESULTS_PER_PAGE : 0,
        RESULTS_PER_PAGE
      ]
    }
  } }
])
```

Comment: What will be the response for this query. Will it return count as well as result

Comment: @Kumar yes, the count is calculated during $group using $sum and the array result comes from $push. You can see in the $project that I include the post count (postCount) then take only a section from the result array using $slice. The final response returns the number of total posts along with only a section of them for pagination.

Answer (score 12):

there is a way in Mongodb 3.4: $facet

you can do

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      data: [{ $match: {} }],
      total: { $count: 'total' }
    }
  }
])
```

then you will be able to run two aggregate at the same time

Comment: Just little update total should be an array like total: [{ $count: 'total' }]

Comment: not working with $sort stage, getting unexpected output. Issue is only exist if using $facet.

Answer (score 9):

> By default, the count() method ignores the effects of the
>   cursor.skip() and cursor.limit() ([MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/))

As the count method excludes the effects of limit and skip, you can use `cursor.count()` to get the total count

```
 const cursor = await database.collection(collectionName).find(query).skip(offset).limit(limit)
 return {
    data: await cursor.toArray(),
    count: await cursor.count() // this will give count of all the documents before .skip() and limit()
 };
```

Comment: Deprecated as of 2023

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on the pagination experience you need as to whether or not you need to do two queries.

Do you need to list every single page or even a range of pages?  Does anyone even go to page 1051 - conceptually what does that actually mean?

Theres been lots of UX on patterns of pagination - [Avoid the pains of pagination](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/avoid-the-pains-of-pagination/) covers various types of pagination and their scenarios and many don't need a count query to know if theres a next page.  For example if you display 10 items on a page and you limit to 13 - you'll know if theres another page..

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB has introduced a new method for getting only the count of the documents matching a given query and it goes as follows:

```
const result = await db.collection('foo').count({name: 'bar'});
console.log('result:', result) // prints the matching doc count
```

Recipe for usage in pagination:

```
const query = {name: 'bar'};
const skip = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize; // assuming pageNo starts from 1
const limit = pageSize;

const [listResult, countResult] = await Promise.all([
  db.collection('foo')
    .find(query)
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(limit),

  db.collection('foo').count(query)
])

return {
  totalCount: countResult,
  list: listResult
}
```

For more details on db.collection.count visit [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

Answer (score 1):

Thought of providing a caution while using the aggregate for the pagenation. Its better to use two queries for this if the API is used frequently to fetch data by the users. This is atleast 50 times faster than getting the data using aggregate on a production server when more users are accessing the system online. The aggregate and $facet are more suited for Dashboard , reports and cron jobs that are called less frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came across this question. The correct solution to this problem is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501115/mongodb-how-do-you-find-and-count-in-the-same-query-with-a-specific-format).

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to get the total result size without the effect of `limit()` using `count()` as answered here:
[Limiting results in MongoDB but still getting the full count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300882/limiting-results-in-mongodb-but-still-getting-the-full-count/15301243#15301243)

According to the documentation you can even control whether limit/pagination is taken into account when calling `count()`:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count

Edit: in contrast to what is written elsewhere - the docs clearly state that *"The operation does not perform the query but instead counts the results that would be returned by the query"*. Which - from my understanding - means that only one query is executed.

Example:

```
> db.createCollection("test")
{ "ok" : 1 }

> db.test.insert([{name: "first"}, {name: "second"}, {name: "third"}, 
{name: "forth"}, {name: "fifth"}])
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 5,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})

> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c5"), "name" : "first" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c6"), "name" : "second" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c7"), "name" : "third" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c8"), "name" : "forth" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c9"), "name" : "fifth" }

> db.test.count()
5

> var result = db.test.find().limit(3)
> result
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c5"), "name" : "first" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c6"), "name" : "second" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58ff00918f5e60ff211521c7"), "name" : "third" }

> result.count()
5 (total result size of the query without limit)

> result.count(1)
3 (result size with limit(3) taken into account)
```

Comment: If you downvote, please add a reason so I have the chance to understand - which might also improve future answers!

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvote but just an FYI: `count()` only works with `find()` and thus is not helpful with `aggregate` queries

Answer (score 0):

Try as bellow:

> cursor.count(false, function(err, total){ console.log("total", total) })

```
core.db.users.find(query, {}, {skip:0, limit:1}, function(err, cursor){
    if(err)
        return callback(err);

    cursor.toArray(function(err, items){
        if(err)
            return callback(err);

        cursor.count(false, function(err, total){
            if(err)
                return callback(err);

            console.log("cursor", total)

            callback(null, {items: items, total:total})
        })
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using 2 query.

```
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit || 50, 10);
    let page = parseInt(req.query.page || 0, 10);
    if (page > 0) { page = page - 1}

    let doc = await req.db.collection('bookings').find().sort( { _id: -1 }).skip(page).limit(limit).toArray();
    let count = await req.db.collection('bookings').find().count();
    res.json({data: [...doc], count: count});
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the two queries approach, and the following code has been taken straight out of a project I'm working on, using MongoDB Atlas and a full-text search index:

```
return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {

    const search = {
      $search: {
        index: 'assets',
        compound: { 
          should: [{
            text: {
              query: args.phraseToSearch,
              path: [
                'title', 'note'
              ]
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }

    const project = {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: '$_id',
        userId: 1,
        title: 1,
        note: 1,
        score: {
          $meta: 'searchScore'
        }
      }
    }

    const match = {
      $match: {
        userId: args.userId
      }
    }

    const skip = {
      $skip: args.skip
    }

    const limit = {
      $limit: args.first
    }

    const group = {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }

    const searchAllAssets = await Models.Assets.schema.aggregate([
      search, project, match, skip, limit
    ])

    const [ totalNumberOfAssets ] = await Models.Assets.schema.aggregate([
      search, project, match, group
    ])

    return await resolve({
      searchAllAssets: searchAllAssets,
      totalNumberOfAssets: totalNumberOfAssets.count
    })

  } catch (exception) {
    return reject(new Error(exception))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon already existing answers,
You can also use `$unwind` & `$set` to make your count much more direct

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { ... } },
    { $sort: { ... } },
    {
        $facet: {
            count: [{ $count: "count" }],
            docs: [
                { $skip: 3 },
                { $limit: 5 }
            ]
        },
    },
    { $unwind: { path: "$count" } },
    {
        $set: {
            "count": "$count.count"
        }
    }
])
```

This should give you an output like this:

```js
[
  {
    count: 48,
    docs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is also another a smooth way to do the pagination data on MongoDB query level:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match: { ... } }, //Define the search criteria here 
{ $sort : { ... }, // sorts the data by specific criteria
{ $facet:
    { 
        count: [ { $count: "total" } ], // Count all documents 
        data: [{ $match: {}}, { $skip: 1 }, { $limit: 2 }] //does the pagination for data
    }, 
},
{
        $project: {
          data: 1,
          count: { $arrayElemAt: ["$count.total", 0] } // Extract count from the array
        }
      }
]);
```

The response should look like this:

```
 {
        "data" : [ 
            [Object], [Object]
            [Object], [Object]...
        ],
        "count" : 100
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in one query. First you run a count and within that run the limit() function.

In Node.js and Express.js, you will have to use it like this to be able to use the "count" function along with the toArray's "result".

```
var curFind = db.collection('tasks').find({query});
```

Then you can run two functions after it like this (one nested in the other)

```
curFind.count(function (e, count) {

// Use count here

    curFind.skip(0).limit(10).toArray(function(err, result) {

    // Use result here and count here

    });

});
```

Comment: This is not correct method.You are just finding in all document instead of first 10 documents in each request.For each request,everytime you are just finding in whole documents. not in first 10.

Comment: thanks for the comment. at the time this is a solution we came up with. it may not be perfect when it comes to efficiency. do suggest a solution to improvise.