# How to get count from aggregate lookup results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am looking to find out the total documents count from aggregate join. is it possible to get count from the below code? if anybody have an idea please let me know.

```
    db.collection("camp", function (err, camp) {
    camp.aggregate([{$match: {status: {$ne: "Rejected"}}}, 
         {'$lookup': {

                from: "organization",
                localField: "organization",
                foreignField: "organizationId",
                as: "orgnData"
            }
        }, {'$lookup': {
                from: "organizer",
                localField: "organizer",
                foreignField: "organizerId",
                as: "ornrData"
            }},
        {$unwind: "$orgnData"},
        {$unwind: "$ornrData"},
        {$match: {'ornrData.city': 'Nagpur'}},

        {$skip: 0}, {$limit: 10}, 
        {$sort: {id: -1}}

    ], function (err, info) {
        res.json(info);
    });
});
```

from above code i am looking to get total rows count of result before limit. if anybody have an idea please let me know?

Comment: You are trying to get a "paging" count in the same query. Don't do that, it's pretty silly. There is a good explanation of "why" around somewhere I am sure. But it should not be too hard to work out you would need to stuff all of your results into an array in a single document just to get the count, then expand that out to "page". Just run a seperate pipeline to "count" and another for "results" in pages. It's How we've been working with database paging for years, and it does not change.

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time @ Blakes Seven

Comment: I'm still spending it. I'm not really happy with the body of response on [Get a count of total documents with MongoDB when using limit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21803405/2313887) but at least is does get to the point. I thought I did or someone else did make specific reference to the `$push` problem here, so I was still looking for the reference. But really, just run this one pipeline for the results and a simple `{ "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } }` for the total count without the "skip" and "limit". Still searching for the reference.

Comment: I'm also still work on that to get a count of total documents when using limit. i tried { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } } by using this i am getting only count but i want full data with count from collections. is there any process to getting data also through this? and one more thing is $group is takes more time to return the results also. please give me any suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

Add to the aggregate the following, removing limit:

```
{ $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @DiegoRBaquero , By using { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } } i am getting only count but i want full data with count from collections. is it possible?

Comment: Then count all the return documents from code