# MongoDB: How to default $count to 0 in a $facet when there is no matching criteria in aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on a complex pagination aggregate query and I am trying to see what Mongo is and isn't capable of doing. I followed this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53220591/6000966), and all works well except for when there is no data returned.

Mongo returns: `{ metadata: [], data: [] }`, but I want to see if it's possible to return

`{ metadata: [ { count: 0 } ], data: [] }`

for the Front-End to handle easier. So far I haven't been able to achieve this.

Here's a snippet of the **$facet pipeline** I'm using :

```json
{
  "$facet": {
    "metadata": [{
      "$count": "total"
    }],
    "data": [{
      "$skip": 0
    }, {
      "$limit": 10
    }]
  }
}
```

Of course this can be done after the query on the back-end, but I'm really wanting Mongo to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check condition at the end,

- `$addFields` to check `$cond` if `metadata` array size is zero then return static array with total count zero otherwise return original metadata array

```
  // <= skipping your pipelines
  {
    $addFields: {
      metadata: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$metadata", []] },
          [{ total: 0 }],
          "$metadata"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UC413qBiYtz)

---

Other option with `$switch` case operator,

- `$switch` to check first case if `metadata` is equal to `[]` then return total with zero and in `default` return original `metadata` array

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      metadata: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: { $eq: ["$metadata", []] },
              then: [{ total: 0 }]
            }
          ],
          default: "$metadata"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y633nLSo7Rh)

Comment: I added to the Playground to show my case. Usually it's a date range where the data does not exist, but I wanted to show how it looks if nothing shows up. https://mongoplayground.net/p/eJSodjH7zUG