# is there a way to use countDocuments() on a resolved query mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have this code

```
async findAll(query: SharedPreferences, req): Promise<IVehicle[]> {
const vehicles = this.vehicleModel
  .find({
    ...req.searchObj,
    ...req.dateQr,
  })
  .sort({ [query.sort]: query.orderBy === "desc" ? -1 : 1 })
  .skip(req.skip)
  .populate(["owner", "branch"]);

const total = vehicles;

vehicles.limit(+query.limit);

const response: any = {
  result: await vehicles,
  // count: total.countDocuments(), // this doesnt work here since vehicles already been awaited
  limit: +query.limit,
  page: +query.page,
};

return response;
```

}

what I'm trying to do is to get the total count of the vehicle documents without the (limit) query and also the vehicles documents (the array result of find()) with one query.

I need to separate the limit() so it doesn't count the vehicles while they are limited in order to get the actual total, but when you await the vehicles you cant access the .countDocuments() anymore since the promise is resolved.

I copied the vehicles into a new total variable which I thought will be different, but since it addresses the same query, it's no use. is there a way to implement this without making 2 queries. thanks

Comment: Have you tried `const total = vehicles.length`?

Comment: @IsiakaLukmanBamidele that wouldnt work because the query is not yet executed to get the length of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` operator on `vehicles`.

```
async findAll(query: SharedPreferences, req): Promise<IVehicle[]> {
const vehicles = this.vehicleModel
  .find({
    ...req.searchObj,
    ...req.dateQr,
  })
  .sort({ [query.sort]: query.orderBy === "desc" ? -1 : 1 })
  .skip(req.skip)
  .populate(["owner", "branch"]);

vehicles.limit(+query.limit);

const response: any = {
  result: await vehicles,
  count: await vehicles.count(),
  limit: +query.limit,
  page: +query.page,
};

return response;
```

You can check more ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803290/get-a-count-of-total-documents-with-mongodb-when-using-limit) to achieve the same if the above doesn't work.

Comment: nope , didnt work, because the vehicles is already executed when result : await vehicles so can't do await vehicles.count() anymore

Comment: Have you checked the link I shared?

Comment: yes, I fixed it, but actually none of them referenced the simple solution which is using clone() to make a copy of the query then get the the length of that copy while the .limit() is not executed, ill post it as an answer so maybe it will be useful for other ppl too.

Comment: or I think .clone() is new, from version 6.0.13

Answer (score 0):

So this worked for me

```
async findAll(query: SharedPreferences, req): Promise<IVehicle[]> {
const vehicles = this.vehicleModel
  .find({
    ...req.searchObj,
    ...req.dateQr,
  })
  .sort({ [query.sort]: query.orderBy === "desc" ? -1 : 1 })
  .skip(req.skip)
  .populate(["owner", "branch"]);

const total = await vehicles.clone().count();

vehicles.limit(+query.limit);

const response: any = {
  count: total,
  result: await vehicles,
  limit: +query.limit,
  page: +query.page,
};

return response;
```

}

you can use .clone() to save a copy of the query, and then get the count of that before the .limit() is executed, so this will return the vehicles, and the total count without the limit.