# Why mongo db (version 3.0.6) returns wrong number of records when we use count with limit option?

Tags: mongodb

As per [mongo db doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) says we can use count with limit.

Limit option is used to specify the maximum number of documents the cursor will return. But if we use limit with count it returns total count and not correct count.

Why?

Suppose we have 50 records in collection then only count option will return 50, and if we apply limit(10) option then it should return 10 and not 50. But count with limit returns 50.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting results in MongoDB but still getting the full count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300882/limiting-results-in-mongodb-but-still-getting-the-full-count)

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find(<query>).count();
```

You will get count of all records found after executing the query. i.e count=50;

```
db.collection.find(<query>).limit(10).count(true);
```

You will get the count of limited documents. i.e count=10.

You should set `applySkipLimit` to true.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/

Comment: As per docs you are right. But actually I am getting count 50 for both cases. And that's my question. Why? You can check by actually executing these queries.

Comment: Great. I've tried to find this answer for a long time. Perfect and fast solution.