# MongoCursor has no count() method?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongo-java-driver

So my code is:

```
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find().skip(20).limit(10);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = findIterable.iterator();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = cursor.next();
    // My stuff with documents here
}
cursor.close(); // in finally block
```

Now I want to know the `total count` of documents before `skip` and `limit`.

There is an [answer for exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300882/limiting-results-in-mongodb-but-still-getting-the-full-count), but I have `mongo-java-driver v3.1.0` and API I use is different.
There is no methods `count()` or `size()` in both [FindIterable](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) and [MongoCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html) classes. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Seems like the only workaround is making another call to mongodb: `collection.count` as said [@Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33874400/1192702)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [count](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#count-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) method can now be found in [MongoCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.1/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html):

```
int count = collection.count();
```

returns the total number of documents in a collection.

```
int count = collection.count(criteria);
```

returns the number of documents in a collection which match the given criteria.

Comment: Thanks, but is it the only way? I have to make secondary request to mongodb

Comment: @alaster whatever you do with the cursor would only give you the count of actually returned documents after applying `limit` and `skip`. Counting all documents in the collection without pagination is an entirely different operation and thus requires a separate request.

Comment: According to mongodb manual this functionality exists in mongo shell - https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/. So maybe there is another solution

Comment: @alaster Note the wording: "The operation does not perform the query but *instead counts the results that would be returned by the query*". It can not do this without querying the database. This implies that calling the count method does in fact create an additional, independent request to the database.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Just want to wait some time for another answers

Answer (score 1):

You should use `MongoCollection.countDocuments(Bson filter)` to calculate exact number of documents. You can also pass additional param `CountOptions options` and specify offset, limit.
[MongoCollection.countDocuments](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.6/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#countDocuments(org.bson.conversions.Bson))

If you need faster response and the exact number is not a must you can also use `MongoCollection.estimatedDocumentCount()`
[MongoCollection.estimatedDocumentCount](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.6/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#estimatedDocumentCount())